# Reverse Engineering Android ROMS to detect malicious code

Tags: malware, android, firmware-analysis

I'm working on reverse Engineering Android ROMS (Firmware you can flash onto your phone) so that I can scan them for malicious behavior. I've been looking all over the internet but unfortunately I'm coming short on any guides to do this or a lead of which to achieve this. My question is, given an android ROM such as the ones you can download online which tools / methodologies have you guys found most effective in dissecting them to detect malicious behavior (such as sending your private data to China for example).

Comment: Yo! It's been a long time this question is open. Did you figure out how to solve your problem? maybe i can help